# Tensorflow - Finding biggest 3 neighbor pixels for each pixel in an image tensor

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am struggling with the locating biggest k pixels in the neighborhood of a pixel. The inputs are `nonetype` dynamic image tensors.

```
versions:
-tensorflow 1.2-gpu
-python 3.5
```

For extracting the neighbors of each pixel in the image tensor I have created an eye filter:

```
w = np.eye(9).reshape((3, 3, 1, 9))
weights=tf.constant(w,tf.float32)
pixel_determ= tf.nn.conv2d(patches_batch, weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME') #shape=(8, 183, 275, 9)
```

resulting tensor will have depth of 9 which includes neighbors and center pixel value itself.

What I need to do is to locate 3 biggest values along the depth for each pixel of image (locations must be preserved) and assign `True` or `"1"` for biggest 3  and  `"0"` or `False` for the rest.

I am kind of confused with the function `tf.nn.top_k`. I could not get the right indices. Besides, I have not yet tried but it seems like it does not accept `None` type data. Is there any tricks or another way of doing this ?

I would really appreciate if I could get any kind of help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of output do you get when using `tf.nn.top_k`?

Comment: It gives only the depth number of the biggest values not the full index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a solution

```
def biggest_k_indices(mat, k):
    _, indices_mat =tf.nn.top_k(mat, tf.shape(mat)[3], sorted=False)
    _, indices_k =tf.nn.top_k(mat, k, sorted=False)
    index= []
    eq =[]

    for i in range(k):
        index.append(tf.expand_dims(indices_k[:,:,:,i],-1))
        eq.append(tf.equal(indices_mat,index[i]))

    bool_comb =tf.logical_or(eq[0],eq[1])
    if (k==2):
        index.clear() 
        eq.clear()
        return bool_comb

    for i in eq[2:]:
        bool_comb=tf.logical_or(bool_comb,i)

    index.clear()
    eq.clear()
    return bool_comb
```

In this function, I am comparing the indices of the tensor with the k biggest indices one by one in the in the loop. Then with the help of `tf.logical_or` I am collecting the `True` values into a single tensor `bool_comb`. I have tested this with only single test array. So I am not sure if it will work 100%.